# unable to add the variable value into a query using f string in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, f-string

I am having a JSON script and I want to add a variable value into it using f-string in python but I was unable to do it.

```py
name = "harsha"
query = """mutation {
                createUsers(input:{
                user_name: f"{name}"
                  })
                  {
                    users{
                      user_name
                    }
                  }
              }
        """
```

[image]
when i am printing query i am getting the same value not the change value `harsha`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything within the triple quotes is interpreted as being part of the string, not as code. Move the `f` in front of the triple quotes to have it be interpreted as an `f`-string.

This will require escaping the rest of the braces, so you'll end up with this.

```
name = "harsha"
query = f"""mutation {{
                createUsers(input:{{
                user_name: {name}
                  }})
                  {{
                    users{{
                      user_name
                    }}
                  }}
              }}
        """
```

Comment: I have tried it and its throwing an error as shown in the figure above @Ryan Pattillo

Comment: @daylightisminetocommand You need to escape the "real" brace characters with `{{` and `}}`. I've added that to the answer.